# How are these to rails functions connected?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am following this tutorial: [Youtube rails tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AMai9EZesXY)

He is creating a basic website where people can add books, review them, rate them, delete them and so on. In the main controller script, he defines a function "new" to add a new book like so:

```
def new
    @book = Book.new
end

def create
    @book = Book.new(book_params)

    if @book.save
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        render 'new'
    end             
end 

def book_params
    params.require(:book).permit(:title, :description, :author)
end
```

He also uses a creat function for that. He has a "new" view named new.html.erb that actually shows the form where users can add a new book and this is related to the "new" function shown in the controller. The new.html.erb file only has this:

```
<h1>new book</h1> 
<%= render "form" %>
```

I get most of it, what I don't get is, since the "new" function doesn't do anything and the "create" function is the one doing all the work for the "new" function, how are they related? I am asking this because the "new" function does not "call" the create function at all but the work the "create" function does is shown in the webpage. Are they connected through "@book"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new` action renders `new.html.erb`, which contains a form to create a new book. When a user clicks `submit` on that form, that new book is created with the `create` action.

I will recommend going to more tutorials and reading the [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) to get a full understanding on how Rails works.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

In Rails the `new` action displays the form for creating a resource.
`create` responds to when the user posts a form.

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  # GET /books/new
  def new
    @book = Book.new
  end

  # POST /books
  def create
    @book = Book.new(book_params)
    # ...
  end
end
```

> I am asking this because the "new" function does not "call" the create
>   function at all but the work the "create" function does is shown in
>   the webpage. Are they connected through "@book"?

You're fundamentally confused about how web applications and MVC work. Web applications respond to requests coming from a user. The server sends a a response and thats it. The program ends. The server does not sit around waiting for the user to click like a desktop program.*

They are not "connected" at all. `new` and `create` respond to a different kinds of requests at different paths. The are never both invoked in same request.

Comment: * there are exceptions but this is generally how web applications work.

Answer (score 0):

The new action shows and initialize the form. What you complete on it before you click on create button will send to the create action of the BooksController. This action will create a new Book object with the params, and save in DB.
This is MVC pattern. You should read about it: https://www.sitepoint.com/the-basics-of-mvc-in-rails-skinny-everything/